# How to break bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, break

Like all the other questions about this, bootstrap puts my ad button in a second line under the other ad button and leaderboard. It only happens between certain widths on the desktop view. So what I want to do is to make the ad buttons on both sides the right and the left, poke out of the bootstrap grid, so that they will not be inline with sidebar or the rest of the website. This is the [link](http://tsn.thesn.net:8080/) to it.

Comment: seeing your markup, you did not understood the Bootstrap grid at all, please read it carefully, it's really easy and fun.

Comment: I see a usecase for breaking from a .container on sites that are managed with a CMS that allows for content to be freely arranged and you don't want to put 20 .containers inside your body but instead assign a special frame 'break to full screen width' to single content elements. Therefore this answer should contain an answer for this case as well. Outside of the bootstrap world this gets solved with a margin: 0 -100%; approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like the row beneath your green nav bar to be wider than the bootstrap grid.

This is easy enough to do. You need to close the bootstrap container just before the row which will be wider, create and close a new div for this extended row, then open a new bootstrap container for the remainder of the page. So the basic structure would be something like this:

```
<div class="container>
   <header> .... </header>
   <div class="navbar"> .... </div> <!-- close navbar -->
</div><!-- close container -->

<div class="wideRow"> .... </div> <!-- close wideRow -->

<div class="container>
<!-- remainder of page -->
</div> <!-- close container -->
```

See a [live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/E5zny/)

FYI, there may also be an issue with some of your divs either not closing or not correctly nested. If you [validate the page](http://bit.ly/Xlm7wn) it's showind some div issues, and if I look at the source code of your page, you are opening container divs @ lines 90 and 217, but they don't seem to close correctly.

Anyway, hope this points you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was really helpful. I fixed the errors from the validator page and used the example to fix my problem. Thanks :D